# Assembly resolving and merged assemblies

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies

Can anyone tell me in what order assembly resolving takes place when I have the following situation?

In my bin I have my exe and 2 dll's:

- Assemblies A (version 1), B and C merged into X (so 4 assemblies into 1)
- Assemblies A (version 2)

all references I made did not include the `UserSpecificVersion` parameter.

- Now, during a call in my exe, which A is being used?
- Also, during a call in assembly B, which A is being used?

And what if it is the other way around (so first from B and then my exe)

Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all references I made did not include the UserSpecificVersion parameter.

I'll assume you actually meant the "Specific Version" setting for a reference assembly and that you set it to False.  This has no effect at runtime, only at compile time.  When you added the assembly, it recorded the [AssemblyVersion] of the reference assembly.  If you then, *later*, recompile your program but it finds a reference assembly with a *different* version then it won't complain but use the new one as-is.  This is in general risky and you'd only do this when you try to limp along after you lost the original reference assembly and have no clue to what degree the new one changed.  Always leave this setting at the default of True, only use False if you dug yourself a deep hole you cannot get out of.

At runtime it will always insist on finding the assembly with the correct display name and [AssemblyVersion] that was recorded from the reference assembly.  You'd in general have trouble when you have two assemblies with the same name and namespaces, you tend to need *extern alias* to dig yourself out of that hole.  Using ILMerge could indeed be a workaround, that changes the display name of the assembly.  That however still leaves you with conflicting namespace+type names, it isn't clear how you sailed around that obstacle.

So the typical outcome is that the EXE will try to find A2, using the renamed assembly display name, and B will try to find A1.  I can't nail it down with 100% fidelity from the provided info.  If you have a non-typical case then use Fuslogvw.exe to get a trace of the assembly bindings.  Be sure to select the "Log all binds" option.